# How to Remove left space on custom tool bar in android

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I have created custom tool bar in my android application.In my application,when I see layout is showing correct but when run application then show more margin from left side.I am extend AppCompatActivity in my Activity.
I have use following code for custom toolbar and XML

**Code**

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // add the custom view to the action bar

```
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_headerbg" >

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backbtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/clear" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBack"
        android:background="@drawable/ico_nav"
        android:contentDescription="@string/clear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Setting"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDeviceList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/headerdevicelist"
        android:contentDescription="@string/clear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please find attached image.I want to remove left space which is marked by red.How to fixed it and suggest me.

[image]

Comment: Is that the space reserved for "setHomeButtonEnabled" ? have you tried disabling it?

Answer (score 0):

Add custom actionbar style in your app:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
  <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and set it in your application theme:

```
<style (your application theme)>
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```